# Jersey global ExceptionHandler doesn't work

Tags: java, exception, jersey, handler

i'm trying to create a global ExceptionHandler in this way:

```
@Provider
public class MyExceptionHandler implements ExceptionMapper<Exception> 
{
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Exception exception) 
    {
        return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity("TEST").build();  
    }
}
```

in order to catch all the exception in the controller:

```
@Path("/policy")
@GET
public void getPolicy(@DefaultValue("no") @QueryParam("_id") String _id) throws Exception{
        int a = Integer.parseInt("test"); // it generates NumberFormatException
}
```

the NumberFormatException isn't handled by MyExceptionHandler.

Where i'm wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the code where you register the ExceptionHandler?

Comment: I didn't register the handler. @Provider should automatically register it. MyExceptionHandler class is in the controller package and if i change the throws with NumberFormatException, handler works! But i need to handle all uncontrolled exception catched at runtime.

Comment: Ah, didn't mind the Annotation, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use jersey < 2.5 it could be a bug while component package scanning:

> @see: https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2175

Otherwise,
 you properly *missed* to add the package of your `MyExceptionHandler` for component scans. The `@Provider` annotation means, that the implementation "**should** be discoverable by JAX-RS runtime during a provider scanning phase", but in fact it does'nt did it like we thought. Probably a bug, but i'm not sure.

*Meaning*: Afaig, you **have to** register package or mapper by yourself - otherwise it will not work for now!

*Note*: I did not tested this with servlet 3.x without Application subclass and basic web.xml @see 4.7.2.3.1. JAX-RS application without an Application subclass [link](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html)

Maybe also interesting:

> [Disable MBW, MBR, ExceptionMapper automatic registration via META-INF/services](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2518)
>
> The jersey-metainf-services (Jersey extension module enabling automatic registration of JAX-RS providers (MBW/MBR/**EM**) via META-INF/services mechanism) was added @since 2.9.x

*For the sake of completeness*:
You can do the registration by using ResourceConfig.packages(String...packages):

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

public class MyResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public MyResourceConfig() {
        packages(new String[] { 
            "path.to.foo", 
            "path.to.bar"
        });
    }
}
```

Alternative in web.xml servlet config

...for packages:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>path.to.foo,path.to.bar</param-value>
</init-param>
```

...for classes

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
    <param-value>
        path.to.foo.MyExceptionHandler,
        path.to.bar.FooBar
    </param-value>
</init-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's worth checking that the `ExceptionMapper` is registered as a singleton. Registering a component as a singleton depends on your framework. Here's a couple of examples:

**Guice**

In your injector instance --

```
Guice.createInjector(new JerseyServletModule() {
    @Override
    protected void configureServlets() {
        /* ... this is where modules are installed and where
         * component dependencies are binded
         */

        bind(MyExceptionHandler.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);

        /* configure filters etc, omitted for brevity */
    }
}
```

**Spring**

In your Spring config

```
<bean id="exceptionMapper" class="my.package.MyExceptionHandler" scope="singleton" />
```

Or using component scanning, mark your `ExceptionMapper` as `@Component` --

Config:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="my.package"/>
```

Annotated class:

```
@Component
@Provider
public class MyExceptionHandler implements ExceptionMapper<Exception> {

}
```